# How to get max of combined columns?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with the following columns:
`filename`, `filetype`, `version` and `revision`.

I want to code a query that will find the *highest* `version` AND `revision` for a `filename` and `filetype`. For example, the following will work:

```
select 
 filename 
,filetype
,max(version + revision) as combined
from dmkr_asline.cmires_lbyi
group by filename, filetype
order by filename, filetype;
```

However, I want to be able to return `version` and `revision` as separate columns so I can join another table. I cannot use `max` on each column because I want the `max revision` of the `max version`.

Comment: Could you please give us a bit more of the table layout? Can you give us some examples of the revision number scheme? Are version and revisions INT values?

Comment: So, revision 12 of version 1 should supersede rev. 1 of version 10?

Answer (score 6):

Using [**`top with ties`**](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to get the row with the highest `revision` for the highest `version` for each `filename` and `filetype`.

```
select top 1 with ties
    filename 
  , filetype
  , version
  , revision
from dmkr_asline.cmires_lbyi
order by row_number() over (
  partition by filename, filetype 
  order by version desc, revision desc
  );
```

---

Alternative using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
;with cte as (
  select
      filename 
    , filetype
    , version
    , revision
    , rn = row_number() over (
        partition by filename, filetype 
        order by version desc, revision desc
        )
  from dmkr_asline.cmires_lbyi
)
select 
      filename 
    , filetype
    , version
    , revision
from cte
where rn = 1
order by filename, filetype
```

---

[**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) version:

```
select distinct
    t.filename 
  , t.filetype
  , x.version
  , x.revision
from dmkr_asline.cmires_lbyi t
  cross apply (
    select top 1
        i.version
      , i.revision
    from dmkr_asline.cmires_lbyi as i
    where i.filename = t.filename
      and i.filetype = t.filetype
    order by i.version desc, i.revision desc
    ) as x
```

---

`inner join` version:

```
select 
    t.filename 
  , t.filetype
  , x.version
  , revision = max(t.revision)
from dmkr_asline.cmires_lbyi t
  inner join (
    select 
        i.filename
      , i.filetype
      , version = max(i.version)
    from dmkr_asline.cmires_lbyi i
    group by
        i.filename
      , i.filetype
    ) as x
    on x.filename = t.filename
   and x.filetype = t.filetype
   and x.version  = t.version
group by
    t.filename 
  , t.filetype
  , x.version
```

Comment: Would using max over partition by filename also be an acceptable answer? I feel like I may be reading OP's question wrong.

Comment: @Shaulinator I don't see why it wouldn't be possible to write a solution using `max() over (partition by ...)` but it may be more work to get both the latest version and the latest revision for that version using that approach.